# Unable to login to EC2 after public key of that user has been deleted?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

My friend is facing a very interesting problem.

He accentually deleted all files in his home folder on EC2, which includes his public key file he used to log in.

However, there're 2 rules set on EC2:

1. User can only login using a private key -- i.e., password login is not enabled.
2. User cannot login using the root account.

Sadly, aside from the root user account, there're only one account set on EC2, whose home folder has been deleted.

Is there any chance to log in again into that server?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If your friend is running on an instance with an EBS backed root volume they can try this procedure:

> Connecting to Your Instance if You Lose Your Private Key
>
> If you lose the private key for an EBS-backed instance, you can regain
>   access to your instance. You must stop the instance, detach its root
>   volume and attach it to another instance as a data volume, modify the
>   authorized_keys file, move the volume back to the original instance,
>   and restart the instance. This procedure isn't supported for instance
>   store-backed instances or instances whose root volume has an AWS
>   Marketplace product code. For more information about launching,
>   connecting to, and stopping instances, see Instance Lifecycle.
>
> To determine the root device type of your instance, open the Amazon
>   EC2 console, click Instances, select the instance, and check the value
>   of Root device type in the details pane. The value is either ebs or
>   instance store. If the root device is an instance store volume, you
>   must have the private key in order to connect to the instance. You can
>   also check the value of Product codes in the details pane to determine
>   whether you're using an AWS Marketplace product code.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair

I've not done it myself and don't want to try it :) but worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. but my friend's virtual machine is not EBS-backed.. I tried making a snapshot about it, but there's no option to build a new instance from this snapshot...

Answer (score 0):

The final solution we took was to rebuild another VPS from sketch. This is definitely not the direct solution, but it works.

However, I'd like to keep this question open to see if there're any better ways to solve this problem -- the problem is very interesting by nature.